# Age as a time-dependent covariate

Tags: survival, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

I have some confusion around time-dependent covariates / coefficients.
I'm trying to run a cox regression with age as a time-dependent covariate. Lets say the variable is age-at-first-drivers-license (yrs) predicting first crash, among numerous other predictors. Once splitting the file time spans many years for a given id, due to another time-dependent co-variate in the dataset -

[id 1 1 1; age 20 20 20; time 5 10 15]

If I want the effect of age to vary time should I enter age as is, or should it be updated at every interval, age+elapsed time -

[id 1 1 1; newage 20 25 30; time 5 10 15]

I'm basically trying to let the effect of age vary over time, and estimate the time-dependent coefficient. I think my confusion lies in the fact that age and time are perfectly correlated. It seems odd to update it. I hope I've made some sense.

Apologies for the matrix notation.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X(t)$ denote the time-dependent covariate representing age at time $t$.

For subject $i$ we thus have $X_i(t) = X_i(0) + t$ where $X_i(0)$ is age at baseline.

For simplicity purpose we consider a model with only one variable.

The Cox regression is hazard-based as follows, for subject $i$:

\begin{align*}
h(t \mid X_i(t)) &= h_0(t) \text{exp} ( \beta X_i(t) ) \\ 
&= h_0(t) \text{exp} ( \beta (X_i(0) + t ) ) \\ 
&= h_0(t) \text{exp} ( \beta X_i(0) + \beta t  )
\end{align*}

Usually $\beta$ is estimated *via* a partial likelihood :

let $T_1 < \dots < T_K$ the $K$ observed failure time. This partial likelihood is written :

\begin{align*}
L(\beta) &= \prod _{i=1}^K \frac{e^{\beta X_i(T_i)}}{\sum_{j : T_j \geq T_i} e^{   \beta X_j(T_i)}    } \\
&=  \prod _{i=1}^K \frac{e^{\beta T_i + \beta X_i(0)}}{\sum_{j : T_j \geq T_i} e^{ \beta T_i  +   \beta X_j(0)}    }
\end{align*}

As $ e^{a+b} = e^a e^b$ the terms $e^{\beta T_i}$ cancelled each other so that the partial likelihood is actually

\begin{align*}
L(\beta) = \prod _{i=1}^K \frac{e^{\beta X_i(0)}}{\sum_{j : T_j \geq T_i} e^{\beta X_j(0)}    }
\end{align*}

That is the estimation of $\beta$ for age as a time-dependent covariate will be the same as for age included as a baseline covariate.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable is "age at first drivers license", thus is does not vary with time and is not a time-dependent covariate so you shouldn't update it.

You estimate the time-varying effect of age by including an interaction between (constant) age and a variable of time.

My answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870975/how-to-model-interaction-of-covariate-with-time-when-proportionality-assumption/53688493#53688493) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50398568/generate-survival-curve-with-both-time-dependent-covariate-and-time-varying-coef/53686296#53686296) might help with implementation.